# Set Image on imageview

Tags: iphone, imageview

i have 2 classes , say class A and Class B.
in class A, i have one button,on that button click, i want set an image on class B's imageview.

How can i set image on imageview of class B from class A?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Declare the imageview from Class B as property (@property(..)), than you can set it's image from outside. 
For more infos read: [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17)